# Working out cost based on time spent - simple math

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

> I did a task, and my hourly rate is $£25$ , I spent a total of $36$ minutes on it, how can I work out the total amount of time spent on the task?

---

My attempt:

I can do this for simple sums such as $30$ mins $= 25/2 = £12.5\implies 25$ mins $= 25/4 = £6.25$ but finding it hard for numbers such as $36$ mins.

Thank you

Comment: You tell us the total amount of time spent was 36 minutes, then ask "how can I work out the total amount of time spent on the task?"  Did you mean to ask the amount of money to bill (per your example) rather than the time?

Comment: 25 mins is not one fourth of an hour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you work $1$ hour $= 60$ minutes and get total $25$ pounds it means you will get $\frac{25}{60}$ pounds per minute. So if you work $36$ minutes you will earn:

$$\frac{25}{60} \cdot 36 = 15 \text{ pounds}$$

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply!